# Multi part Identifier

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

```
var details = cab.Bookings.SqlQuery("Select * from Booking where Email =" + Session["Email"].ToString());
return View(details.ToList());
```

This is my code and i am getting this exception

> the multi-part identifier could not be bound

Comment: Don't create queries by concatenating strings. Imagine what would happen if someone added `1; drop table Booking;--` as an email. Even if you add quotes, one can enter `'; drop table Booking;--`. Use parameterized queries instead, proper LINQ queries or use a microORM like Dapper

Answer (score 2):

If the email address in question is e.g. `abc@def.com` your SQL will end up as

```
Select * from Booking where Email = abc@def.com
```

...can you see what's missing? Single quote marks are needed around the email because it's a string literal, not a SQL keyword or SQL object name. It needs to be

```
Select * from Booking where Email = 'abc@def.com'
```

But the way to achieve that safely, reliably and to protect your code against maliciuous SQL injection attack is to use proper paramaterised queries. **Never** inject data values direct into your SQL like that.

---

Now, it looks like you're using Entity Framework? If so you can do the query using Linq to Entities e.g. if `Bookings` is a table then

```
var details = cab.Bookings.Where(b => b.Email = Session["Email"].ToString());
```

would be the conventional way to generate this query. EF will then take care of creating an appropriate, safe query for you. No need for any raw SQL here.

Comment: No problem. Please use this Linq method to create your queries wherever possible, from now on. https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/querying-in-ef-core.aspx has a simple intro

Comment: P.S. If the answer has helped you please remember to mark it as "accepted" (click the tick mark next to the question so it turns green). This will help others understand that it was a useful answer if they read it in future. Thanks :-)